# Why does my IdentityUser ICollection property not load on ASP.NET Core 5.0?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a many-to-many relationship between `AppUser : IdentityUser`, and `TaxAccount`, which is an abstract class that separates into `Household` and `Business`. I want to query how many `TaxAccounts` a User has access to on load.

Here's the `AppUser` class.

```cs
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public virtual List<TaxAccount> Accounts { get; set; }
    }
```

Here's the `TaxAccount` classes.

```cs
    public abstract class TaxAccount
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<AppUser> Users { get; set; }
    }

    public class Household : TaxAccount
    {
        [MaxLength(1000)]
        public string HomeAddress { get; set; }
    }

    public class Business : TaxAccount
    {
        [EmailAddress, MaxLength(500)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

However, when I attempt to query the `AppUser` object in my Razor page, *AppUser.Accounts is null*! As a result, I always return to the "NoAccount" page.

```cs
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            AppUser = await _manager.GetUserAsync(User);

            // Checks how many TaxAccounts the user has.
            if (AppUser.Accounts == null)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("NoAccount");
            }
            else if (AppUser.Accounts.Count == 1)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("Account", new { accountID = AppUser.Accounts[0].ID });
            }
            else
            {
                return Page();
            }
        }
```

I've found that if I use a .Include() statement to manually connect TaxAccounts to AppUsers, the connection sticks! I just have to insert a .ToList() call that goes nowhere. My question is: why do I need this statement?

```cs
AppUser = await _manager.GetUserAsync(User);
_context.Users.Include(X => X.Accounts).ToList();

// Now this works!
if (AppUser.Accounts == null)
```

EDIT: I've tested removing virtual to see if it was a lazy loading thing, there's no difference.

Comment: We need a custom `UserManager` as the origin implementation of `MSIdentity` doesn't aware of the existence of either `Household` or `Business`. `_context.Users.Include(X => X.Accounts).ToList()` would crawl the whole `User` table with including `Accounts`, which should be avoid. Since `AppUser` instance still tracked in EFCore, then it would be update, but again, this is not the way to go.

Comment: Interesting. However, doesn't UserManager use EF Core in the base class? I already defined Household and Business to be abstract classes of TaxAccount in ApplicationDbContext. If I linked TaxAccount to some other object, the relationship would be loaded by default.

Comment: `UserManager` in this case use EF Core, but `GetUserAsync` method was implement to get the only information it needed (which doens't have `.Include(X => X.Accounts)`), so, the accounts information would not be loaded. That's the way MS Identity organize their code, and that's reasonable actually, you can find out a bit more [here](https://gordonkhanhnguyen.dev/posts/2021/how-identity-work-in-asp-net-core#assembly-organization-)

Comment: Thanks for the read! I'll look through this post + the ASP docs to figure out more! In the meantime, it seems like I have 3 options:
1) Remake the ```UserManager``` class to explicitly .Include() the relationship. Unless ```UserManager<AppUser>``` is customizable by default, this seems like a lot of work.
2) Create a second ```AppUser``` class that only retrieves non-sensitive info that links to the identity table, and leave ```IdentityUser``` as the main user of that table.
3) Explicitly call the query with ```await _context.Entry(AppUser).Collection(X => X.Accounts).LoadAsync();```

Comment: I think we should definitely go for option 1, all we need is just make our own class inherit from the origin `UserManager`, override `GetUserAsync` (and may be 2-3 frequently using method), register it with DI and we're good to go (actually, I don't think that could grow above 100 lines of code in all files)